# jquery ui selectable() and sortable() combine

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using a twitter jquery plugin to display a list (ul/li) of twitter posts .

Also I want my users to be able to rearrange the posts as they want and I want the moved post to be marked. 
I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390786/jquery-ui-sortable-selectable) how to do so. 
If I use this the selectable function doesn't work(I can rearrange but can't select):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".ul_sortable" ).sortable().selectable();
});
```

If I use this the sortable function doesn't work(I can select but cant re arrange):

```
$(".ul_sortable" ).sortable().selectable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the sortable `handle` option as shown in the link to the other question.

Sortable and selectable both take over the mouse events for the items they are applied to, however the `handle` option allows you to apply the sorting to a part of the item therefor allowing selectable to work on the rest of the item.

It should also be noted that selecting a bunch of items then sorting them all together is not natively supported.

For marking if an item is moved you can use a variety of sortable events such as `stop` and `change` [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop)