# JQuery UI, sortable and selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm having difficulty combining jquery sortable and selectable.

I have two lists, and want to be able to drag from one list to the other (which works without selectable)

But with selectable rather than dragging it just selects again, is there a way to disable select on selected items or to put the drag-handle on the outside of the select-handle so they don't interfere.

Here's the code.

```
$(function() {
  $(".available, .assigned").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected",
    handle: ".handle"
  });

  $(".available, .assigned").selectable({ filter: "li", cancel: ".handle" })
  $(".available, .assigned").disableSelection();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MJYRD/

This is as far as i've been able to go following this question [jQuery UI sortable & selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390786/jquery-ui-sortable-selectable)

thanks

Comment: What is wrong with just using the code snippet from that linked answer? With that snippet, I easily [got this to work](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/vLM94/).

Comment: when you drop it only drops the dragged item and not the other selected items, i've got to the stage where i'm implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my workaround for making a list selectable and sortable and allows for lasso implementation. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MooseEagleShark/9xft9f1r/).

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Sortable with Selectable</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$(function() {
//

$('body').selectable({
    filter: 'li'
    //filter: '#album2 > li'
});

/*
Since the sortable seems unable to move more than one object at a 
time, we'll do this:

The LIs should act only as wrappers for DIVs.

When sorting a LI, move all the DIVs that are children of selected 
LIs to inside the sorting LI (this will make them move together);
but before doing that, save inside the DIVs a reference to their
respective original parents, so we can restore them later.

When the user drop the sorting, restore the DIVs to their original
parent LIs and place those LIs right after the just-dropped LI.

Voilá!

Tip: doesn't work so great if you try to stick the LIs inside the LI
*/

$('.connectedSortable').sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    delay: 100,
    start: function(e, ui) {
        var topleft = 0;

        // if the current sorting LI is not selected, select
        $(ui.item).addClass('ui-selected');

        $('.ui-selected div').each(function() {

            // save reference to original parent
            var originalParent = $(this).parent()[0];
            $(this).data('origin', originalParent);

            // position each DIV in cascade
            $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
            $(this).css('top', topleft);
            $(this).css('left', topleft);
            topleft += 20;

        }).appendTo(ui.item); // glue them all inside current sorting LI

    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.item).children().each(function() {

            // restore all the DIVs in the sorting LI to their original parents
            var originalParent = $(this).data('origin');
            $(this).appendTo(originalParent);

            // remove the cascade positioning
            $(this).css('position', '');
            $(this).css('top', '');
            $(this).css('left', '');
        });

        // put the selected LIs after the just-dropped sorting LI
        $('#album .ui-selected').insertAfter(ui.item);

        // put the selected LIs after the just-dropped sorting LI
        $('#album2 .ui-selected').insertAfter(ui.item);
    }
});




//
});


<style>
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#album {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#album2 {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#album li  {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

#album2 li  {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}


#album div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;

    background: #F6F6F6;    
}
#album2 div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;

    background: #F6F6F6;    
}
#album .ui-sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: none;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
#album2 .ui-sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: none;
    visibility: visible !important;
}

#album .ui-selecting div, 
#album .ui-selected div {
    background-color: #3C6;
}

#album2 .ui-selecting div, 
#album2 .ui-selected div {
    background-color: #3C6;
}

#anotheralbum {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>


<body>

<ul id="album" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="li1"><div>1- First</div></li>
    <li id="li2"><div>2- Second</div></li>
    <li id="li3"><div>3- Third</div></li>
    <li id="li4"><div>4- Fourth</div></li>
    <li id="li5"><div>5- Fifth</div></li>
    <li id="li6"><div>6- Sixth</div></li>
    <li id="li7"><div>7- Seventh</div></li>
    <li id="li8"><div>8- Eighth</div></li>
</ul>

<ul id="album2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="li1"><div>1- 1</div></li>
    <li id="li2"><div>2- 2</div></li>
    <li id="li3"><div>3- 3</div></li>
    <li id="li4"><div>4- 4</div></li>
    <li id="li5"><div>5- 5</div></li>
    <li id="li6"><div>6- 6</div></li>
    <li id="li7"><div>7- 7</div></li>
    <li id="li8"><div>8- 8</div></li>
</ul>
<div id="anotheralbum" class="connectedSortable">
another album - no style for the lists inside here
</div>

<br style="clear:both">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it somewhat working. [Check the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/ExxaU/)

Basically, I used the [`jquery.multisortable`](https://github.com/iamvery/jquery.multisortable) plugin which extends the default `sortable` widget. This way, you can select multiple items by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking them. You can drag to re-order and/or move items between lists.

Alternatively, if you want to stick to your original mechanism with selection rectangles and drag handles, you can still use `selectable` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/vLM94/)). The only downside is that the `multiselectable` behaviour behind `multisortable` stays active, which means that it still attempts to handle Ctrl+clicks (but fails). It's just a minor nuisance and you can probably tweak the code of `multisortable` so it does not extend `multiselectable` which should solve this.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I think I have my own solution. I'm using events in selectable and in sortable to make them work together.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech What is not working for you? Also, if you solved your own question, you can add the solution as an [answer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/self-answer). Other users with a similar question may then later find this question and find your solution helpful.

Comment: your demo under jsfiddle doesn't seem to be doing anything. but yes, i should have to solution. i'll post it when i'm finished.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech You mean the demo with selection rectangles and drag handles? What are the exact steps you're doing? I can select and drag items just fine.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech Ah, I see. I thought I could use the raw script file from `multisortable`'s GitHub project, but it doesn't serve the right MIME type. Firefox doesn't seem to care, but other browsers do. I updated both fiddles to have the script embedded, it should work now. In a real application, you'd upload `jquery.multisortable.js` to your own server and include it with a `<script>` tag but I couldn't do that in a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Because a drag action is more or less the same action as doing a selection you have to cancel selection if an item has already been selected.

```
$(".available, .assigned").selectable({ 
    filter: "li", 
    cancel: ".ui-selected"
})

$("available, .assigned").sortable()
```