# Order photos with drag and drop and multi-select with Ctrl and Shift?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a photo gallery and a grid of thumbnails. Is there a jQuery or JS package I can use to allow drag and drop sorting of the thumbnails?

Something similar to this:

http://demos.codexworld.com/dragdrop-image-reorder/

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

BUT I also require the ability to select multiple photos at once to sort. `Ctrl + click` to select individual images in aggregate, BUT also `Shift + click` to select all images between and inclusive of two images.

[jQuery Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) only supports `Ctrl + click`. There is nothing for `Shift + click`.

This looks promising:

https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable

Any other recommendations or some kind of industry standard package that I might be unaware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI sortable & selectable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390786/jquery-ui-sortable-selectable)

Comment: @Aguardientico not quite. That post is missing the Shift + click and Ctrl + click requirements.

Comment: Please review it. It has the Ctrl + click it is the work of "selectable" plugin

Comment: There's no Shift + click.

Comment: You could develop `shift + click` function yourself by detecting `shift` button pressed and then add elements from start to end into selected group