# Jquery UI sorting multiple table row at once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with jqueryui sorting.

Now i have a table with sorting on tr and it's all working, but now i have to sort 2 row at once. In the example below i have to sort together row with G1 or G2 or G3.

Now after having beaten my head against the wall for hours i'm here to ask for help.

Queryui sort have the option *item*, i try to use it but can't make itwork in table.

There is a way to do that? Anyone can help me?

I try here https://jsfiddle.net/n29ekt42/

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>T1</th>
            <th>T1</th>
            <th>T1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>G1</td>
            <td>G1</td>
            <td>G1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G1</td>
            <td>G1</td>
            <td>G1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G2</td>
            <td>G2</td>
            <td>G2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G2</td>
            <td>G2</td>
            <td>G2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G3</td>
            <td>G3</td>
            <td>G3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G3</td>
            <td>G3</td>
            <td>G3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

   function assignSortAttach() {

    $("table tbody").sortable({
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            var aa = $this.attr('data-row');
        }
    })
}

// TR sortable
$(function () {
    assignSortAttach()
});
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here, nor told us what you're trying to do...?

Comment: Take a look at using Selectable with Sortable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that this was more difficult than I anticipated, so I took a stab at it. I forked your fiddle and made some updates.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/n29ekt42/13/

I added a handle column.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span></td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td>G1</td>
    </tr>
...
```

Lots of CSS, if you like.

**CSS**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead tr {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

table tbody tr {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tr.ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

tr.ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function assignSortAttach() {
  $("table tbody").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      cursor: "grabbing",
      handle: ".handle",
      opacity: 0.6,
      helper: function(e, item) {
        console.log("Parent-Helper: ", item);
        if (!item.hasClass("ui-selected")) {
          item.addClass("ui-selected");
        }
        // Clone selected elements
        var elements = $(".ui-selected").not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').clone();
        console.log("Making helper: ", elements);
        // Hide selected Elements
        item.siblings(".ui-selected").addClass("hidden");
        var helper = $("<table />");
        helper.append(elements);
        console.log("Helper: ", helper);
        return helper;
      },
      start: function(e, ui) {
        var elements = ui.item.siblings(".ui-selected.hidden").not('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
        ui.item.data("items", elements);
      },
      update: function(e, ui) {
        console.log("Receiving: ", ui.item.data("items"));
        $.each(ui.item.data("items"), function(k, v) {
          console.log("Appending ", v, " before ", ui.item);
          ui.item.before(v);
        });
      },
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.item.siblings(".ui-selected").removeClass("hidden");
        $("tr.ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");
      }
    })
    .selectable({
      filter: "tr",
      cancel: ".handle"
    })
}

$(function() {
  assignSortAttach();
});
```

This is adapted from the code here: [jQuery Sortable - drag and drop multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077146/jquery-sortable-drag-and-drop-multiple-items) and here: [jQuery UI sortable & selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390786/jquery-ui-sortable-selectable)

Credit for using Sort and Select together goes to [mhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932282/mhu). This works really well, since you can drag-select or CTRL+Click to select the Rows as you like. You can drag and select a group or click unqiue items that will group ion the drag. Then using the drag handle, the user can sort the selected rows.

[TJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333214/t-j) gives us the ability to sort multiple items. His Demo is designed to move elements between separate lists, so I switched events `receive` with `update`.

From flippant comment to an answer, I hope that helps.

**Updates after Comments**

---

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lbu7ytbj/

I change the **HTML** to group the rows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><span data-group="1" class="handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span></td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td>G1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td>G1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><span data-group="3" class="handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span></td>
      <td>G2</td>
      <td>G2</td>
      <td>G2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G2</td>
      <td>G2</td>
      <td>G2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><span data-group="5" class="handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span></td>
      <td>G3</td>
      <td>G3</td>
      <td>G3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G3</td>
      <td>G3</td>
      <td>G3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now all I had to do was adjust the `sortable` to use the table and not use the `thead`.

```
function assignSortAttach() {
  $("table").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    cursor: "grabbing",
    handle: ".handle",
    cancel: "thead",
    opacity: 0.6,
    placeholder: "two-place",
    helper: function(e, item) {
      if (!item.hasClass("selected")) {
        item.addClass("selected");
      }
      console.log("Selected: ", $(".selected"));
      var elements = $(".selected").not(".ui-sortable-placeholder").clone();
      console.log("Making helper from: ", elements);
      // Hide selected Elements
      $(".selected").not(".ui-sortable-placeholder").addClass("hidden");
      var helper = $("<table />");
      helper.append(elements);
      console.log("Helper: ", helper);
      return helper;
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
      var elements = $(".selected.hidden").not('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
      console.log("Start: ", elements);
      ui.item.data("items", elements);
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Receiving: ", ui.item.data("items"));
      ui.item.before(ui.item.data("items")[1], ui.item.data("items")[0]);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $('.selected.hidden').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  assignSortAttach();
  $(".handle").attr("title", "Use me to drag and sort.");
});
```

I also added CSS for the placeholder:

```
.two-place {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 0;
}

.two-place::after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: So what are you looking for?

Comment: Must be moved two specific line at once. Row 1 and 2, row 3 and 4, row 5 and 6 and so on.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani you did not explain that in your question. So I did not know that was a requirement. This makes it much easier. I will provide an update in a bit.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani will there be row groups that have more than 2 rows? Or will it always be groups of 2?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani when dropping the grouped items, should they split another group up?

Comment: Always 2 and always grouped.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani now that you have clarified the issue further, I have been able to update my answer. It does what you have described. I hope you will mark it as the answer.